# Output column number according to active sidebars

Tags: widgets, sidebar, columns, php, footer

```
    $sidebars = array(
            is_active_sidebar( 'footer-4' ),
            is_active_sidebar( 'footer-3' ),
            is_active_sidebar( 'footer-2' ),
            is_active_sidebar( 'footer-1' ),
    );

    $col = 0;

    foreach ( $sidebars as $sidebar ) {

        if ( $sidebar ) {
            $col++;
        }

    }

    echo 'col-'.$col.'';
```

What i am trying to accomplish is have the correct number of WordPress active sidebars outputted. So that they can be styled with css example: if 3 sidebars are active you get col-3 if (1) if you col-1.

The code above works. My concern is can it be improved, is this the right way to do it ? Or can increments be used for example: $i = 0; $i++; instead of an array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `array_filter()` function, which will remove every array element that has false as the value. Then you can count the array length. So your example would look like this:

```
$sidebars = array(
        is_active_sidebar( 'footer-4' ),
        is_active_sidebar( 'footer-3' ),
        is_active_sidebar( 'footer-2' ),
        is_active_sidebar( 'footer-1' ),
);

$active_sidebars = array_filter($sidebars);

echo 'col-'.count($active_sidebars);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Wordpress Codex: is_active_sidebar()

> This Conditional Tag checks if a given sidebar is active (in use).
>   This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either TRUE or FALSE.
>
> Any sidebar that contains widgets will return TRUE, whereas any
>   sidebar that does not contain any widgets will return FALSE.

So you should be able to do something like this:

```
$col = 0;

if( is_active_sidebar( 'footer-4' ) ) $col++;
if( is_active_sidebar( 'footer-3' ) ) $col++;
if( is_active_sidebar( 'footer-2' ) ) $col++;
if( is_active_sidebar( 'footer-1' ) ) $col++;

echo 'col-'.$col;
```

Or maybe even:

```
$col = 0;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
  if( is_active_sidebar( 'footer-'.$i ) ) $col++;
}

echo 'col-'.$col;
```

**NOTE:** I've not had time to test either of these methods.